# Editor buttons are out of alignment

Tags: bug, ui

The editor buttons are out of alignment.

[image: Editor buttons out of alignment]

This is occurring in Chrome 38.0.2125.111, Firefox 33.1, and Internet Explorer 11.0.

Comment: Norepro in Safari 7.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be resolved now as the vertical bars have been removed.

[image: Removed vertical bars]